# spring mvc dynamic list binding particular value becomes empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dynamic-list

I have a very peculiar problem. I am developing a web application in Java and Spring MVC. I have a row that can be duplicated dynamically by the user on the press of a button. Each row has around 10 fields. I am binding these rows as list of objects in the backing bean and initializing this list as a lazy list in the bean. Now, it has been working fine till now but the user tried to enter 12 rows and on the 12th row, i.e., the 11th iteration(the iteration starting from 0), the 5th field becomes empty, although the user enters values and all the other fields retain their values. Since the binding happens with name, I have checked the name of the field, it is consistent with the rest of the fields in the same row and the rest of the rows. I am unable to debug and rectify the issue. This is affecting the code in production.

I can provide whatever code snippets are required.

Can somebody please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried executing the same code on a different server and it works fine there but still persists on the live server. And the problem seems to be only in the 11th iteration's 5th field. Could it be a problem with the server

Adding code:

JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${addProposal.requirements}" var="req" varStatus="status">
<!--Rest of the fields-->
    <form:input path="requirements[${status.index}].sampleSize" id="r_sample${status.index}" value="${addProposal.requirements[status.index].maximumFeasibility}" class="inptform2" style="width:65px;" size="10" onchange="functions();"/>
<!--Rest of the fields-->
<td width="57" align="left" valign="middle" id="btn-close" class="btn-remove">' + 
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/btncross.png" width="18" height="17" border="0" />' + 
    '</a>
</td>
</c:forEach>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Add more dynamic rows
        $("#addMore").click(function() {    
             var tr_temp=$("#requirement tr:first").clone();
             //rest of the fields code
             tr_temp.find("#r_sample0").each(function() {
                 $(this).attr({
                        'id': function(_, id) { return 'r_sample' + i},
                        'name': function(_, name) { return 'requirements[' + i + '].sampleSize'},
                        'value': ''
                });
                }).end();
             tr_temp.find("td:last").remove();
             tr_temp.append(btn_close);
             tr_temp.appendTo("#requirement");
             i++;                       
        });

        //To remove a dynamically added row
        $("#btn-close").live('click',function(){
            doNotDel=false;
            count=0;

            //To fetch the values of the Input Fields
            $(this).parent().find("input").each(function(){
                count++;
                var value = $(this).val();
                var id=$(this).attr('id');              
                if(id.indexOf("r_total")==-1){
                    //Skip the minutes and currency column
                    if(id.indexOf("minutes")==-1 && id.indexOf("currencyValF")==-1 && id.indexOf("currencyVal")==-1){
                        if(value!=""){
                            doNotDel=true;
                            return false;       //breaks the .each loop
                        }                       
                    }
                }
            });

            if(doNotDel==false){
                $(this).parent().remove();  
            }               
        });
});
```

Bean:

```
private List<RequirementBean> requirements;

//in constructor
requirements = LazyList.decorate(
                new ArrayList<RequirementBean>()
                , new InstantiateFactory(RequirementBean.class));
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addProposal", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProposal(@ModelAttribute("addProposal") ProposalBean proposal, ModelMap model){
    RequirementBean req;
    List<RequirementBean> reqmtList;

    System.out.println("Before empty rows");
    reqmtList = proposal.getRequirements();
    for(int i=0; i<reqmtList.size(); i++){
        req = reqmtList.get(i);
        if(req.getCountry()!=null){
            System.out.println("sample size " + i + " :" + req.getSampleSize());
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I tried changing the value of the 4th row in the same column, and now the code seems to work. I am still not able to understand what is the issue.

Hope this gives more clarity. Please help me.

Comment: One can not spot this kind of problem without code. - So yes please post the code snippets.

Comment: @Ralph: I have checked that on submit the values are present in the field in jsp. But when the object reaches the controller, the field is empty. So, what code should I post

Comment: have you also checked the submit http request? are the values presented in this request? (For example use Firebug-Network-Monitor)

Comment: @Ralph I changed the value of the 4th field in the same row and now it works.  I am still unable to figure out the issue